# How to show that a stochastic process is Markov

Tags: probability, markov-chains

How can I prove that a given stochastic process is a Markov chain.

Assume the following process:

Joey is walking in the woods. at every turn: 
if at the previous turn Joey turned left then he will turn left with probability p and will turn right with probability 1-p.
if at the previous turn Joey turned right then he will turn right with probability q and will turn left with probability 1-q.

Now, I want to show that this process is a Markov chain. this is very clear by intuition, because every step is dependent only on the previous one.
but I just don't know how to show it in a mathematical way.

Comment: What is "this process"? The sequence of positions or the sequence of displacements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be Joey's decision on the $n^{th}$ turn.

$$X_n = \cases{0\text { If he turns left}\\1\text{ OW}}$$

Now,

$$X_{n+1}=\cases{0\text{ w.p. p if }X_n=0\\1\text{ w.p. (1-p) if }X_n=0\\0\text{ w.p. (1-p) if }X_n=1\\1\text{ w.p. p if }X_n=1}$$

Since Joey's state at any point can be established as a recursion on his previous state (and other constants terms), it is a Markov Chain by definition .

Note: There are very many ways of writing this. I used the one I prefer the most. You can also talk in terms of conditioning for e.g. $X_{n+1} \; |\;X_n=$ blah blah.